# What causes an openmp program to run some threads in D state for large dataset size?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, openmp, htop

I am implementing an OpenMP multithreaded program on following machine.

```
x86_64, On-line CPU(s) list:   0-23
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             2
```

It is a multithreaded clustering program. It shows expected speedup for dataset size upto `2 mil rows` `~ 250 MB data` but while testing on larger dataset, many of the threads in `htop` shows `D state` and CPU% substantially less than `99-100%`. Note that for datasize upto this size, every thread runs in `R state CPU% ~100%`. The running time becomes `~100` times more than sequential case.

Free memory seems to be available and `swp` memory is 0 for all cases.

Regarding data structures used, there are 3 shared data structures size O(n) and then each thread is creating its private linked list that is stored for merging step further. I suspected its because of the extra memory utilised by this per thread data structure, but even if I comment it out program shows the same problem. Please let me know if I should provide more details.

I have only picked up OpenMP and parallel computing few months back so please let me know what can be the possible problems?

Comment: How many threads do you use?

Comment: For size greater than 2 mil rows, it drastically slow downs for any level of multithreading. Even for 2 threads

Comment: Hard to tell but I'd guess you have a bug. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It tends to be a large project with modular code structure and seems difficult to share. I can share the snapshot of htop screen while running as otherwise output is really indefferent to the running time. Otherwise, it will be helpful if you could suggest some commands/ ways to evaluate the multithreaded code wrt memory and efficient thread sharing